# table construction code formatting

Tags: lua, code-formatting, lua-table

Most popular code formatting for table population is

```
mytable = {
  key1 = value1,
  key2 = element2,
  key3 = GetValue3()
  key4 = this_is_the_fourth,
  key5 = and5,
  }
```

but I believe the following is better:

```
mytable = 
  { key1 = value1
  , key2 = element2
  , key3 = GetValue3()
    key4 = this_is_the_fourth
  , key5 = and5
  }
```

The benefit imo is that with the former you easily spot missing commas. I explicitely made the example to illustrate this. Did you spot it?

There is [this guide](https://www.lua.org/pil/3.6.html) on how to construct tables, but there's nothing like python's PEP.

Are there any drawbacks to construct a table like this?

Comment: It's unusual but fine, except that a comma is missing before `key4`.

Comment: @lhf with intention, see the comment below the code

Comment: A considerable amount of people use that style in SQL queries, so it's not too far fetched.

Comment: The compiler is always ready to point you to a missing comma, so emphasizing on syntax is not necessary.  IMO, good code style should emphasize on user domain objects and their relationship.  <_offtopic_> Moreover, every computer program is actually a graph, so (non existing yet) good program editor should manipulate graphs instead of lines of characters. <_/offtopic_>

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You're correct, but I'm writing code that's running on an embedded target and we don't have a test-environment (yet), all testing needs to happen on the target; so is compilation; if I spot these typos early on, less time lost on testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's none from compiler's point of view: extra whitespace is simply collapsed.

Other developers might mentally choke on this for a second though.